# Is an unexpired lock token required to abandon a message in Service Bus?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am using the C# Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus SDK.

The documentation mentions that a ServiceBusException will be thrown if the message lock has expired - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver.abandonmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet#exceptions

In my testing I have a lock duration of 60 seconds on a queue. In my message handling code, I introduce a artificial delay of 70 seconds and then abandon the message. This seems to be successful as no exception is thrown.

Note that I have set `MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration` to zero, so the lock is indeed expiring and not being renewed.

This leads me to believe that an expired token can be used to call the Abandon method, contrary to the documentation.

Comment: AztecCodes is correct.  The Service Bus service isn't precise with expiration timing and tokens will sometimes remain valid for some fuzzy period after their expiration time.   Since you're only delaying 10 seconds past the expiration time, there's a very good chance that the token is still considered valid.

Comment: What Jesse said. Plus, @sideshowbarker, deleting a **correct** answer was rushed and wrong. Please undo it, as the general recommendation provided in the answer by AztecCodes was absolutely solid.

Comment: @JesseSquire is there any documentation that describes this "fuzzy" behaviour? I have tested the same 70 second artifical delay with a 10 second lock duration on the queue and the token is still considered valid when I abandon...

Comment: There is not, unfortunately.   If you're thinking that the service is not correctly expiring tokens, your best path forward would be to open a support request.   (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)  As far as the SDK is concerned, it plays no part in determining expiration.  You ask to settle a message, it invokes the service operation to do so.  The service alone makes the decision.